# jquery - pass text on the page into a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a link that calls a javascript function, and I want to pass the text of the link into the function.

I am trying to create a dialog that displays the name on the original link.
Would jquery be helpful here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly if this is what you are looking for but:

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">Some Text here</a>

$('#mylink').click(function(){ myfunc($(this).text()); return false; });
```

Comment: what does this code do?  i am trying to have the text in the link show up on a confirmation dialog

Comment: it is just a rough example, but basically it is taking the text inside of the <a> link, and passing it to myfunc() as an argument. myfunc is just an example function name.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery UI has a [dialog function](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default) which would make it easy.

I'd create a hidden div:

```
<!-- Temporary elements --> 
<!-- ui-dialog --> 
<div id="dialog" title=" "> 
</div>
```

And in $(document).ready add:

```
jQuery('#dialog').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     width: 625, 
     position: 'center'
}); /* end #dialog */
```

Then, in the click event of the link, set the title and text as:

```
jQuery('.ui-dialog-title').text(/* yourtext */);
jQuery('.ui-dialog-content').html(/* link name or whatever */);

jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open');
return false;
```

Those classes are automatically added by the dialog.

edit: forgot to mention, you'll want to open the dialog in the same click event and return false so the original link href doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

A non jQuery way of doing this is to just assign a simple onclick handler to the link

```
<html>
<head>

    <script>
         function foo(link)
            {
                alert(link.innerHTML);
                return false;
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="foo(this);">blah</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the previous answer, if you just want a dialog box it should be (jquery required):

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">Some Text here</a>

$('#mylink').click(function(){ alert($(this).text()); return false; });
```

Comment: where do you put the following code?

$('#mylink').click(function(){ alert($(this).text()); return false; });

anywhere in the page?

Comment: if you just want a dialog alert, you can put in the link's onclick event: "function(){ alert($(this).text()); return false;}"